# Terrafrom - connection issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, connection, terraform, ssh-keys

I am trying to connect to private ec2 instance through Bastion server using Terrafrom. But Terrafrom script ask the question "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" and i am not able to pass the answer "yes" to it. hence execution is not complete.

I have tried with -input=false also .. but no success

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Update the instnaces by installing newrelic agent using remote-exec
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

resource "null_resource" "copy_file_newrelic_v_15" {

  count = "${length(aws_instance.bastion.*.ami)}"

  triggers = {
    cluster_instance_ids = "${join(",", aws_instance.bastion.*.id)}"
  }

  connection {
    host = "${element(aws_instance.bastion.*.public_ip, count.index)}"
    user = "ec2-user"
    private_key = "${file("C:/keys/nvirginia-key-pair-ajoy.pem")}"
    agent = "true"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {

    connection {
        agent = "true"
        bastion_host = "${element(aws_instance.bastion.*.public_ip, count.index)}"
        bastion_user = "ec2-user"
        bastion_port = 22
        bastion_private_key = "${file("C:/keys/nvirginia-key-pair-ajoy.pem")}"
        user = "ec2-user"
        private_key = "${file("C:/keys/nvirginia-key-pair-ajoy.pem")}"
        host = "172.31.2.218"
    }

    inline = [
      "ssh ec2-user@172.31.2.218" 
    ]
  }

}
```

Actua execution should be pass through after getting answer to "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" question. manually or programetically.

I need to pass "yes" to Terraform for this question, which will be accepted by Terraform and will complete the execution

```
 null_resource.copy_file_newrelic_v_15 (remote-exec): Connected!
null_resource.copy_file_newrelic_v_15: Still creating... (10s elapsed)
null_resource.copy_file_newrelic_v_15 (remote-exec): The authenticity of host '172.31.2.218 (172.31.2.218)' can't be established.
null_resource.copy_file_newrelic_v_15 (remote-exec): ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:0uaLK1VDcuHwwzCDM0GWba6RTTL4gD/hWaONHigPNyE.
null_resource.copy_file_newrelic_v_15 (remote-exec): ECDSA key fingerprint is MD5:f6:b0:39:f8:3a:dc:92:4f:c1:d9:c2:9d:13:6a:79:0a.
null_resource.copy_file_newrelic_v_15 (remote-exec): Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
null_resource.copy_file_newrelic_v_15: Still creating... (20s elapsed)
null_resource.copy_file_newrelic_v_15: Still creating... (30s elapsed)
null_resource.copy_file_newrelic_v_15: Still creating... (40s elapsed)
null_resource.copy_file_newrelic_v_15: Still creating... (50s elapsed)
null_resource.copy_file_newrelic_v_15: Still creating... (1m0s elapsed)
null_resource.copy_file_newrelic_v_15: Still creating... (1m10s elapsed)
null_resource.copy_file_newrelic_v_15: Still creating... (1m20s elapsed)
null_resource.copy_file_newrelic_v_15: Still creating... (1m30s elapsed)
null_resource.copy_file_newrelic_v_15: Still creating... (1m40s elapsed)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the exact error/prompt you get?

Comment: Thanks , I have added the console output ..

Comment: What are you even trying to achieve here? The `remote-exec` runs on the target host so you're currently trying to SSH from the instance back to itself. Also you'd need to pass `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` if you wanted to avoid the host key check.

Comment: I have two servers . 1) Bastion Host 2) Private Instance  .. I am running Terraform script to login into bastion server first and from there into Private instance to run a script. Stuck where Terraform script is trying to login from bastion into private server.

Comment: No you're not. The `bastion_*` parameters already handle jumping through the bastion to the specified `host`. If you change that `ssh` command to something like `hostname` you'll see.

Comment: Thanks ..it works .. :) .. your point "rying to SSH from the instance back to itself" help me to find the issue ..thanks again